# 2-е проблемы: скрол и button в опере.

Tags: jquery, html, css, javascript

Есть страничка:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>xiper.net - пример работы плагина jquery.color</title>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="js/jquery.scrollTo-min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                jQuery(document).ready(function(){

                    jQuery('header button').click(function() {
                        str = jQuery(this).val();
                        jQuery.scrollTo("#"+str , 500);
                    });

                });
            </script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                <div style="height: 70px; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 20px; bottom: 0;">
                    <button value="anchor1" id="bHome" class="m_point_valid ease5" onMouseOver="m_pointOver('0');" onClick="m_pointClick('bHome')" onMouseOut="m_pointOut()">Главная</button>
                    <button value="anchor2" id="bAboutUs" class="m_point ease5" onMouseOver="m_pointOver('130px');" onClick="m_pointClick('bAboutUs')" onMouseOut="m_pointOut()">О нас</button>
                    <button value="anchor3" id="bWhatWeDo" class="m_point ease5" onMouseOver="m_pointOver('260px');" onClick="m_pointClick('bWhatWeDo')" onMouseOut="m_pointOut()">Что мы делаем</button>
                    <button value="anchor4" id="bContacts" class="m_point ease5" onMouseOver="m_pointOver('390px');" onClick="m_pointClick('bContacts')" onMouseOut="m_pointOut()">Контакты</button>
                    <div id="underline" class="ease5"></div>
                </div>
            </header>
            <div id="body">
                <div id="anchor1" style="width: 100%; height: 70px; background: #234;"></div>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 750px; background: #535; position: relative;">
                    <div id="anchor2" style="position: absolute; bottom: 70px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 750px; background: #789; position: relative;">
                    <div id="anchor3" style="position: absolute; bottom: 70px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 750px; background: #365; position: relative;">
                    <div id="anchor4" style="position: absolute; bottom: 70px;"></div>
                </div>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 750px; background: #567; position: relative;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <footer style="width: 100%; height: 300px; background: #142; position: relative;">
            </footer>
            <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

на ней 2 проблемы:

1. В опере при нажатии на `button` текст внутри двигается, как то мне это не нравится, но я так и не додумался как это убрать.
2. При нажатии на кнопку скрол перемещается на заданный обьект, но вот если скрол прокрутить на другой элемент в ручную то меню бездействует. Как вытянуть событие изменение скролла и его значения так чтобы можно было понять на каком обьекте сейчас скрол и изменить меню ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первая проблема решается хаком, [e.g.](http://jsfiddle.net/8a972/9/):

```
button { padding: 9px 20px; } 
noindex:-o-prefocus, button:active { padding: 8px 21px 10px 19px; }
```

По поводу второй проблемы - непонятна верстка ваша верстка, что значит "изменить меню" и т.п. Но предполагаю, что вам может пригодится [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#about) - плагин, отслеживающий появление элементов в области видимости.